# Invalid Identifier SQL coursework

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I am currently working on some SQL coursework, this is my code so far:

```
CREATE TABLE VEHICLES
  ( 
     Vehicle_id            VARCHAR(6)  PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
     Vehicle_Make          VARCHAR(18), 
     Vehicle_Model         VARCHAR(25), 
     Passenger_Number      INT,
     Number_Owned          INT,
     Registration_Date     DATE, NOT NULL UNIQUE
     Colour                VARCHAR(10), 
     Rate                  INT
  );
```

Each time I try and run the statement it gives me

> SQL ERROR: ORA-00904: invalid identifier

Comment: On `Registration_Date`, there is a misplaced comma

Answer (score 1):

You have a comma at the wrong place.

Here it is corrected:

```
CREATE TABLE VEHICLES
  ( 
     Vehicle_id            VARCHAR(6)  PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
     Vehicle_Make          VARCHAR(18), 
     Vehicle_Model         VARCHAR(25), 
     Passenger_Number      INT,
     Number_Owned          INT,
     Registration_Date     DATE NOT NULL UNIQUE,
     Colour                VARCHAR(10), 
     Rate                  INT
  );
```

Comment: Thank you very much, silly mistakes are often the ones I overlook most!